# Typescript Polymorphic component typing not working

Tags: typescript, polymorphism, typescript-typings, react-typescript, framer-motion

I'm trying to create a polymorphic component, but I don't understand the error that is throwing. Would appreciate some assistance and perhaps an improved version.

The expected outcome is that I should be able to pass the `as` prop. e.g

```js
<Text as="button" onClick={e => {}}>
    Hello World
</Text> 
// <button onClick={...}>Hello World</button>

<Text as="div" onClick={e => {}}>
    Hello World
</Text>
// <div onClick={...}>Hello World</div>
```

#### [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4AFHMAZwHlMAeAMJwaMJADsAJlzgBrJIwiY4AKQDKADQB0ASXEwowcV2BoAogBskICTBkAfRMRhb1Gy9duCIxgwFcMaH4UcUYAPjC4AF5yOFVNLQAZYAAjKBQoRgBZEJQAcyRJAEEYA1S-MS4hABondBdvcB9bDghuAHVgGAALCArkAUEIyiYWOCKuVrAhEWoxKRlkeq0PG30AFWYkSKi4AG9YuAB6ACoTw7gT8fE4CAA3JChDSVYlBm7WF8wUPwt4AAl1llEgx8loLldBCE4CgLFwIHAUqwQhAeo86hg4GhcJBxLZwXFLkdDiguAB%20ABccEE5AAvpRTudLuMLBYIAB3GSYaCzeaSIx5GFwLhIeBvMCcGQACgABmY5hIXpIplwZQBKRGMGE3e6PZ4C4Wi27KCVtLixK6yngPJ7AF4q9W1CRcPyGcSCnooeAhLWSPxgCymL1IGQZV4254vG4pLVo24Ru0Ci2GsUmyUEk7Emh0eCjVjyvkoFJWFX8AuKwoq6L7Wm1a16u1IKu7Pa0nZweu2%202SuAAMkOPBAXTLCqklcltXkimUneeTclYQZZ2TRVZHK5PKMH0MMANcdN3Dg2Fw71YXBYaGAmGAhREVjWua2woRnpgyYPMkD8ix3WAFkkRDiLUaAWKSXAAHIoDYfbCkwVhwOy0CyLUpIIUgrIwjI6GePoAC055IJe15oMmXplCkFQhnAX7IoYKBwDgVhcFocDrB8WI4s0%20hwLKgjqnAIB%20Fw8BInAYBgbeRgZlmtDQI%20Yx6NuXRFlYqwtJKMyiIqizOCs962JsLC1M2NbtuWUgqfOZr8IcKp8EIYTVLZkrkIu5CMiuAnQGebS-sJQZiJIcA2iYPjGnAMqKY8ynFkgan6A6CHbkgyb7hJQVGBFpIymJnAIX%20FhwC8YhQEOeJJaY3S5WaWLQqJRggX4SoWjJOYME%20bAQBYjAgNAYC-mgjS4up1mHMIWkLBiLjxTAhlIE5cQma2TntlFO6WTNpaCMZPa9uMkycA5bkecyACqu6Bkw7VjDACKiOkmJxjKRCYDlB5HjgeD0ZA3W9VA-WmBxTR4voLVULJ9B5uwXU9X1A0DJpo7SFNek4bNWztksGBaENXEwCqnQ9AjQwANoAOQvWTAC6S5MlcRQIekYAsFA4Uyp1v1w6YuMg-jko5a%20MJwgiDUWE1VFPS9Mrvnl3Ks-uMN-QDaBA8NoNEuDbVQxzsP-QNPMjR0XTdAjY28tpKMzXNC3sD2La1q51Y60r%20ucbzW07WakR7XsDFIJglLQ5zeumMTkT0uQUPrKIW3m5NWPTfpGwY07itc4NbuG1whMm-7NlxNthy%20-SYQUJHT7R3MBvcbsiN8jpyxW0%20uz4OeIT4GEUqHB%20VKV3z1lDOQGpRJECdaAnM1wI4fhjteeKSGX2ZyRxvisaIveiNX8C7GPcvshkkgDF3cR1xbY9N2MLdt%20IHfH4SvuksBXXQMBv7-oBcC0hvcxbY5Fx%20wHKkzt05h0OMPSIBxCQr2EtSTONdMJT0cK3cSN8y5QOxKvYSjB4K7GxGyVmZJ9iwWwUgKkvs8E8lpJ-OAZDaRoMJEQGArobh3ygUIOB8A9haG4VgqwVCXpRD2C9Ns-8oF7DQG-ACEh6RQJPkcLei4oFqgoHEekyigA)

I forgot to mention that the component should correctly infer the type when passing it to Framer motion

```js
import { motion } from 'framer-motion'

...

const Body = motion(Text)

<Body as={} /> // should infer the types
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is this:

```
Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Omit<TextProps<ElementType<any>>, "ref"> & RefAttributes<unknown>>' is not assignable to type 'TextComponent'.
  Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | undefined'.
    Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | undefined'.
```

That middle line stands out:

```
Type 'ReactNode' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | JSXElementConstructor<any>> | undefined'.
```

Your `TextComponent` is typed to return `React.ReactElement`, but typically you would expect a component to return the `React.ReactNode` type instead.

If you change that everything works.

```
type TextComponent = <C extends React.ElementType = "span">(
  props: TextProps<C>
) => React.ReactNode | undefined;
```

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4AocpAD0ljhgE8wk4AFHMAZwHlMAeAMJwaMJADsAJlzgBrJIwiY4AKQDKADQB0ASXEwowcV2BoAogBskICTBkAfRMRhb1Gy9duCIxgwFcMaH4UcUYAPjC4AF5yOFVNLQAZYAAjKBQoRgBZEJQAcyRJAEEYA1S-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-sJQZiJIcA2iYPjGnAMqKY8ynFkgan6A6CHbkgyb7hJQVGBFpIymJnAIX+FhwC8YhQEOeJJaY3S5WaWLQqJRggX4SoWjJOYME+bAQBYjAgNAYC-mgjS4up1mHMIWkLBiLjxTAhlIE5cQma2TntlFO6WTNpaCMZPa9uMkycA5bkecyACqu6Bkw7VjDACKiOkmJxjKRCYDlB5HjgeD0ZA3W9VA-WmBxTR4voLVULJ9B5uwXU9X1A0DJpo7SFNek4bNWztksGBaENXEwCqnQ9AjQwANoAOQvWTAC6S5MlcRQIekYAsFA4Uyp1v1w6YuMg-jko5a+MJwgiDUWE1VFPS9Mrvnl3Ks-uMN-QDaBA8NoNEuDbVQxzsP-QNPMjR0XTdAjY28tpKMzXNC3sD2La1q51Y60r+ucbzW07WakR7XsDFIJglLQ5zeumMTkT0uQUPrKIW3m5NWPTfpGwY07itc4NbuG1whMm-7NlxNthy+-SYQUJHT7R3MBvcbsiN8jpyxW0+uz4OeIT4GEUqHB+VKV3z1lDOQGpRJECdaAn4EQC8cCOH4Y7XnikgUEcRyEmvcQAHo-iEBRBT0wDmprckcb4rGiL3ojV-Auxj3L7IZJIAxd3EdcW2PTdjC3bfiB3z+Er7pJgJdWgMBX8-5AJwFpBfOYW1HIXD9gHKkzt05h0OMPSIBw17YlPlfasqF7COFbuJH+ZcsE+GErBRg8FdjYjZKzMk+xKFWCpL7WhPJaSQLgCw2kpDCREBgK6G4f815CEztxPYWhJHCSoUgDhL0oh7Bem2eBa89hoDAQBCQ9J15wH4EcK+i415qgoHEekxjKDYIoQAKy4NQas-Awh6LCEAA)

---

`ReactNode` includes `ReactElement` and is defined as:

```
type ReactNode = string | number | boolean | React.ReactElement<any, string | React.JSXElementConstructor<any>> | Iterable<React.ReactNode> | React.ReactPortal | React.PromiseLikeOfReactNode | null | undefined
```

So you are getting this error because `forwardRef` returns a type that cannot be assigned to the more narrow `ReactElement`. It could return `null`, for example, which is totally valid, but does not match the `ReactElement` type.

Comment: Thanks. That is indeed correct. I was confused between ReactNode and ReactElement. However, with the change above, the typing isn't being inferred when trying to render the component. No props are showing up. I believe that because of passing it to `motion()`?